# Connecting cordova app with IP/Network printer

Tags: cordova, printing, cordova-plugins

Hi I am working on an cordova pos app which require network printer to connect and printing invoices. I found bluetooth printer plugin and its working perfectly now I am searching for network printer connection. If any one can help then your help will be very important for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: not yet..... :(